# How to restrict user-generated content in SQLite database to that user

Tags: flutter, sqlite, authentication, firebase-authentication, sqflite

I have an app that I've created through Flutter. It makes use of an SQLite database to allow the user to store user-generated data. It also requires authentication using Firebase, where each user must have an account, in order to log into the app.

Just today, I noticed that when I signed into the app on my phone using a different tester account to the main one I use, I had access to everything in the SQLite database that was created with my other account, with this new account, which took me a little by surprise.

Is there a way to restrict user-generated content to that specific user? By that I mean that if one user logs into the app on a device and creates some content, a different user will not see that content if they were to log into the app using their account on the same device?

To handle the database and add entries into it, I have built this code which works perfectly:

```
  static final DatabaseClientCalculations instance =
      DatabaseClientCalculations._init();
  static Database? _database;
  DatabaseClientCalculations._init();

  /// Calling the database
  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database!;
    _database = await _initDB('calculationsDatabaseV6.db');
    return _database!;
  }

  /// Future function to open the database
  Future<Database> _initDB(String filePath) async {
    final path = await getDatabasesPath();
    final dbPath = join(path, filePath);
    return await openDatabase(dbPath,
        version: 11, onCreate: _create, onUpgrade: _update);
  }
```

To create a new entry in the database, I use this:

```
  Future<CalcResult> create(CalcResult calcResult) async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    final id = await db.insert(calcResults, calcResult.toJson());
    return calcResult.copy(id: id);
  }
```

To read a specific database entry, this is what I use:

```
  Future<CalcResult> readNote(int id) async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    final maps = await db.query(
      calcResults,
      columns: CalcResultFields.calcValues,
      where: '${CalcResultFields.id} = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );

    if (maps.isNotEmpty) {
      return CalcResult.fromJson(maps.first);
    } else {
      throw Exception('ID $id not found');
    }
  }
```

To display all entries in a ListView, this is what I use:

```
  Future<List<CalcResult>> readAllNotes() async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    final orderBy =
        '${CalcResultFields.toDate} DESC, ${CalcResultFields.toTime} DESC';
    final result = await db.query(calcResults, orderBy: orderBy);
    return result.map((json) => CalcResult.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
```

As I say, this does work perfectly, with the exception that it seems that any user can view any other user's data. It seems I incorrectly assumed that due to the authentication, no user would see anyone else's content.

Is there a way to restrict access to database entries to only those who created those entries? What can I do to restrict user-generated content to that user only?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have each entry of the data item created in the database one of the columns has the id of the user that created it.

Then in the query function would would pass the user id along with the reset of the search criteria to get only the records that the user id created and therefore is permitted to access

Comment: Good idea, thanks! I'm sure that's something I could sort, for sure. One question though, how would it work for the calculations that have already been made? I'm happy that I know how to edit the existing tables to add the new column, but how would I basically ensure the app automatically updates the existing calculations with the user's ID?

Comment: Now you have 'dirty' data - you need to run a script that runs through the dataset and populates that new column correctly.  How you will figure out which post was created by which user idk ‍♂️

Comment: Well my app is young/small enough that it is more than likely only the same user has created all entries at this point. Either way you're right, I don't actually have a proper way of knowing this. I'm sure I will figure something out though, thank you!